# Write an integral to represent the area of the shaded portion of the rectangle shown in Figure 1.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

Can someone please help me with this question? I've no idea how I'm supposed to do that with an integral:

Write an integral to represent the area of the shaded portion of the rectangle shown in Figure 1. Check your answer.

[image: Figure 1]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The shaded area would be equal to the integral for the area under the upper "curve" ([-1,1] to [1,3]) less the integral for the area for the lower "curves" ([-1,1] to [0,0] and [0,0] to [1,1] also known as f(x)=|x|).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is the area between the function $x\mapsto 2+x$ and $x\mapsto |x|$.